# NSRunLoop only to run untill all the events are finished

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsrunloop

There are method in NSRunLoop and CFRunLoop, To run to particular time
CFRunLoopInMode and NSRunLoop - runUntillDateT

These methods specify a time to run until.

But, I wanted process all the messages in the runLoop and exit if it is done and idle.
Because some of the runLoop sources can have indefinite time to process. So, I cannot mention the time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `CFRunLoopRunInMode` to run the event loop for one pass, and it tells you whether it handled any sources.  So you can try something like this:

```
while (CFRunLoopRunInMode(kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, 0, 1) == kCFRunLoopRunHandledSource) {
    // nothing
}
```

Another approach you could try is to create a `CFRunLoopObserver` with an `activities` argument of `kCFRunLoopBeforeWaiting`.  This observer will be called just before the run loop goes to sleep waiting for a source or timer to fire.  In the observer's callout, you can simply call `CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurrent())`.